# How can I set PHPExcel to write a file and use gridlines?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to set up the print options for an excel file in PHPExcel. I'm working from the packaged API documents (version 1.7.7) but can't find any methods to do this. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

This setting is found in MS Excel under Print > Page Setup > Sheet.

Comment: `PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup` - look at the documentation for this class.  Could not find up-to-date docs set online directly, but you can [download a zipped PDF](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/504328) of it, [this is an older version elsewhere](http://www.grad.clemson.edu/assets/php/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setPrintGridlines(TRUE);
```

**EDIT**

setPrintGridlines() identifies whether gridlines around cells should be displayed when printing a worksheet from MS Excel; the default is FALSE. setShowGridlines() identifies whether gridlines around cells should be displayed when the spreadsheet is shown in the MS EXcel GUI; the default is TRUE;

Comment: How do we set this when converting into PDF. I want the gridlines to appear on my generated PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the one I was looking for. It was under the Worksheet class and not the page setup class as I'd previously thought. 
For anyone looking in future, this is the method you need:

```
PHPExcel_Worksheet setPrintGridlines( [boolean $pValue = false])
```

There are two functions very similar though: setPrintGridlines and setShowGridlines. I'm not quite sure of the difference. Can anyone enlighten me?